# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory with php - scandir

Tags: php, laravel, file-get-contents, scandir

I'm using Laravel 5.1
In folder /public/download I have many .htm pages I need to get so I write:

```
public function scraper() {

 $path = 'downloads/';
$files = scandir($path);
foreach ($files as $k => $file) {
    if ($k < 2) continue;
  $html = file_get_contents($file);

//parse the html into a DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@class='merchant-links']/a/@href");

echo $hrefs;
}
}
```

but I got error:

***ErrorException in AdminController.php line 133:
file_get_contents(1742-wine-bar-1.htm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory***
[image]
I also try:

```
 $path = 'C:/wamp/www/mavis/public/downloads/';
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve my problem with:

```
$files = glob('downloads/*.{htm}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
$html = file_get_contents($path.$file);
```

because here in $html variable your have only a filename, but you must include a directory path in function `file_get_contents()`